# Read from a file in C++

Tags: c++

4;
Spadina;76 156
Bathurst;121 291
Keele;70 61
Bay;158 158

This is what file contains in it. I need to read them and save them into variables.

4 is for dynamic memory allocation. 4 means there are 4 stations.
Spadina, Bathrust, etc.. they are station names. first number, which comes right after station names, is number of student passes and the second number is number of adult pass.

So, basically I have 4 variables and they are;

```
int numberOfStation;
int studentPass;
int adultPass;
string stationName;
```

I spent 4 hours but still cannot read the file and save it into variable
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you have by now?

Comment: Have you looked online, in a book, etc. for information about [C++ I/O](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2b%2b%20i%2fo)?

Comment: Please, please, please, search StackOverflow for "c++ read from file" to get a plethora of examples on how to input data from a text file. [Examples of reading data files](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+from+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group your variables in struct.

```
struct MyStruct
    {
        int studentPass;
        int adultPass;
        string stationName;
    };
```

Now read size of struct in file and allocate it dynamically

```
MyStruct *p;

s >> N;
p = new MyStruct[N];
```

Now in for loop you read string with delimiter `';'` and other two vars are ints

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    getline(s, p[i].stationName, ';');
    s >> p[i].studentPass >> p[i].adultPass;
}
```

Where var `s` is istream type of variable with flag `std::in`

Comment: I love that use of `getline` I didn't even think of that. I'm going to steal that for use in my `operator>>`.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is to read every line with e.g. [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) then parse each such line string. You'll use the appropriate methods of [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to search inside it (with [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)) and split it (with [substr)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). You might also access some individual character in that string using [at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) or the `[]` operator of `std::string`; alternatively, you might perhaps parse each line -or relevant parts of them- using [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) (I am not sure it is appropriate in your case). You might be interested by [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)...

An important thing is to define *exactly* (not only thru examples) the possible acceptable inputs. You could for example use some [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) to formalize that. You should probably care about [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (try first by assuming a simple single-byte encoding like [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), then later consider [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) if your system uses it).

For example, can the station names (I guess you talk about subway stations) contain digits, or spaces, or underscores, or commas, etc.... ? Could they be French [names](http://www.ratp.fr/) like *Hôtel de Ville* (a metro station in central Paris) or *Saint-Paul* or [*Bourg-La-Reine*](http://www.bourg-la-reine.fr/) (where I am), or Russian names like [Молодёжная](http://www.mosmetro.ru/stations/arbatsko_pokrovskaya/molodezhnaya/) in Moscow? (I guess that station names in Tokyo or in Jerusalem might be even funnier to parse).

BTW, explicitly entering the number of entries (like your initial `4`) is very user-unfriendly. You could have some lexical conventions and e.g. use some tagging or separators.

At last, you might want to keep the information for every travel. Then you'll probably need to define some `struct` or `class` (not simply four *scalar* variables). At that point your program is becoming more interesting!

Comment: How can I parse lines?

Comment: As I explained, by using appropriate searching and splitting.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a `struct` to hold your stations:

```
struct station{
    string _stationName;
    int _studentPass;
    int _adultPass;
};
```

Then create an operator to use with your struct (props to [Sly_TheKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357248/sly-theking) for the `getline` idea):

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, station& rhs){
    getline(is, rhs._stationName, ';');
    is >> rhs._studentPass >> rhs._adultPass >> ws;
    return is;
}
```

Say that your `ifstream` is called `foo`. You can read these into a `vector` like this:

```
foo.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

vector<station> bar{istream_iterator<station>(foo), istream_iterator<station>()};
```